# Listing all usb mass storage disks using python

Tags: python, usb, detection

I have few USB disks inserted in my system. I would like to list all of them like:-

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
.... ans so on..
```

Please remember that I don't want to list partitions in it like `/dev/sdb1`. I am looking for solution under Linux. Tried `cat /proc/partitions`.

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  488386584 sda
   8        1   52428800 sda1
   8        2   52428711 sda2
   8        3          1 sda3
   8        5   52428800 sda5
   8        6   15728516 sda6
   8        7  157683712 sda7
   8        8  157682688 sda8
  11        0    1074400 sr0
  11        1      47602 sr1
   8       32    3778852 sdc
   8       33          1 sdc1
   8       37    3773440 sdc5
```

But it list all the disks and unable to figure which one is USB storage disks. I am looking for a solution which does not require an additional package installation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you use the lsusb command or are there other USB devices connected other than storage devices?

Comment: Yes. Some time USB modem also connected. But I want to list only USB block disk as mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert Klaus D.'s suggestion into Python code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

basedir = '/dev/disk/by-path/'

print 'All USB disks'

for d in os.listdir(basedir):
    #Only show usb disks and not partitions
    if 'usb' in d and 'part' not in d:
        path = os.path.join(basedir, d)
        link = os.readlink(path)
        print '/dev/' + os.path.basename(link)
```

`path` contains info in this format:
`/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0`
which is a symbolic link, so we can get the pseudo-scsi device name using `os.readlink()`.
But that returns  info in this format:
`../../sdc`
so we use `os.path.basename()` to clean it up.

Instead of using
`'/dev/' + os.path.basename(link)`
you can produce a string in the `'/dev/sdc'` format by using
`os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), link))`
but I think you'll agree that the former technique is simpler. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your script is looking good. But I need to get only the USB mass storage disk. Your script also list `/dev/sr1`, which is a cdrom. Also, when I checked the mode to find if device is mass storage device, it returened block for all devices, including cdrom. Here is the part of code `mode = os.stat(""/dev/sdb).st_mode
        print mode`

Comment: @sundar_ima: The simple solution is to filter `link`  to eliminate entries that contain `'/sr'`, or  filter it to only include entries that match `'/sd'`.

Answer (score 0):

List the right path in `/dev`:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/*-usb-* | fgrep -v part
```